# Spring Internationalization Error in Java file

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to send an SMS message with template from messages_en.properties from a .java file.

My WebMvcConfig file is:

```
    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("i18n/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
        return messageSource;
    }
```

My .java file is:

```
content = messageSource.getMessage("delivery.otp.sms.template", new Object[] {"123456"}, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())
```

and my file is in main/resources/i18n/messages_en.properties

```
delivery.otp.sms.template=Your OTP is {0}.
```

But I got error:

> No message found under code 'delivery.otp.sms.template' for locale 'en_US'

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I found the error: My .java file is a `@Service`, not a `@Controller`. I read from here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626926/cant-get-message-from-messagesource-outside-controller). Question is: How do I get it from the `@Service` class? What changes to be made to my Spring config?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `classpath:` in your basename. So the final code would be like below:

```
@Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/i18n/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
        return messageSource;
    }
```

The reason is that if you do not add `classpath:` it will consider the given path as a `abosolute` path but since we have relative path (`main/resources/i18n/messages_en.properties`) here, its better to add `classpath:`so, spring will look from the direcotry where jar is running.

Comment: Didn't work. I'm still getting the same error. Please help.

Comment: How do you fetch `MessageSource` instance? Do you use `@Autowired`  with `@Qualifier` ?

Comment: I used @Autowired

Comment: Add `@Qualifier('messageSource')` as well and change your property file name to `messages_en_US.properties`

Comment: I changed the file name and added @Qualifier. But still the same error.

Comment: ok I have edited my ans. I have aded `/` in front of `i18n` in path. So final path would be like `classpath:/i18n/messages` can you try now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214095/discussion-between-saurabh-and-alant).